# PHP print in Basic page

Tags: 7

I am facing what I think it is a strange behavior...

I have a Basic Page with PHP code in it. In this PHP code, I have some "Print".

Now, no matter the page I am displaying on the website, I got those prints in the bottom of my page...

Is that normal? How can I change that?

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

This is working as intended.

> I have a Basic Page with PHP code in it. In this PHP code, I have some "Print".

You should *not* have any PHP (not "print" or anything else) as part of the *content* of a node.  Drupal is designed to treat PHP in nodes as text, and will just output it verbatim. Anything else would create a huge security hole in your site.

Just delete those "print" statements, and they will no longer appear.

Comment: Ok! That seems legit! But Then, how can I display some text in that page only? Is this possible?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what it is you try to do. You can have text both in a node and a block. You can also make a node and a block appear on one page only if you want to. If that is not what you want, ask a new question and spell out in detail what you want to do.